# Export DEM file of specific places and import into VBS3

Tags: dem, google-earth

I want to get a DEM file to load into [VBS3](https://bisimulations.com/tools/vbs3).

I followed the instruction from the internet that use Google Earth Pro.

Here is the link: [The instruction that I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE10OyfUAm4)

But the DEM file I've gotten from the instruction seems not suitable for my purpose.

This is the result when I load the DEM file into VBS3 (after I apply textures, clutters,...):
[image]

Is there another way to get DEM file of specific place in order to load it into applications?

Comment: If you want to include an image, you need to use the SE image facility, since best security practice forbids following links.

Comment: @Vince Thanks, let me edit my question.